# cannot find protocol declaration custom protocol delegate iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Slowly but surely getting this delegation and protocol stuff on iphone but I cannot understand this error.

I have declared my protocol in my first viewcontroller.

In the second viewcontroller i try to add it at the top after i have imported it into the header file and it cannot find it. see my code below.

//SendSMS

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginPage.h"
#import "MessageOptions.h"

@protocol SMSProtocol <NSObject>

-(NSString *)postbackType;

@end


@interface SendSMS : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {

    id<SMSProtocol> delegate;

    MessageOptions *messageOptions;
    LoginPage *loginPage;
    IBOutlet UITextField *phonenumber;
    IBOutlet UITextView *smsBody;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<SMSProtocol> delegate;

-(IBAction)LoadMessageOptions;

@end
```

Then my second view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SendSMS.h"

@interface ScheduledSMS : UIViewController <SMSProtocol>{



}


-(IBAction)popBack;

@end
```

Comment: This should work good ... there seems no problem with this code

Comment: I had the same problem, I just moved files in the navigator and error was gone.

Comment: Check your included files.<br>
This is symptom of two mutually included headers.<br>
Sometimes it cause this error.

Answer (score 2):

That is surely strange. Have you tried restarting Xcode? Xcode has a habit of not indexing symbols for me when I add new files.

You should also look into how your naming conventions. `SendSMS` is not really a good class name, more of a action method name. I would go for `SendSMSViewController`, since that is what it is.

By that it would follow that `SMSProtocol` should be named `SendSMSViewControllerDelegate`, since that is what it is.

Methods in a delegate protocol should contain the sender and one of the three words *will*, *did*, or *should*. If not at the very least it should name what it expects to return. `-(NSString *)postbackType;` should probably be `-(NSString *)postbackTypeForSendSMSViewController:(SendSMSViewController*)controller;`.

Comment: thanks for the advice. maybe you can assist me a little further. I have 3 views. the user goes through each view, 1, to 2, to 3. then selects something in the 3rd view and data should then be past back to the 1st view on popBackToRootViewController. This is all in a navigation controller.... I have spent pretty much the last few days trying to work it out... and know tutorials i have found are even similar to my situation.

Comment: @MrPink - The design for the three views setup is probably better suited for a question of it's own. Might need a big longer reply, than a comment allows for.